# Always block being ignored

Tags: verilog

As part of a larger program, I'd like to activate the green LEDs one at a time on my DE2 board in their order (0 to 8) when I press KEY[1]. They should turn off one at a time in reverse order when I press KEY[2]. I'm pretty sure that DE2 board keys are active low. This is my code:

```
always@(negedge KEY[1], negedge KEY[2])
begin

    if(~KEY[1])
    begin
        LEDGValue <= LEDGValue << 1;
        LEDGValue[0] <= 1;
    end

    else if(~KEY[2]) 
        LEDGValue[0] <= LEDGValue >> 1;

end
```

Instead all the green LEDs light up as soon as I load the program. At this point KEY[1] and KEY[2] have no effect. Anyone see something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an edge detector.

```
module edge_detector (
    input wire clk,
    input wire in,
    output wire negedge_out
);

reg in_reg= 1'b0;

wire in_next = in;

assign negedge_out = ({in_reg,in) == 2'b10);

always @(posedge clk) in_reg <= in_next;

endmodule
```

Here is how you use an edge detector.

```
reg [8:0] LEDGValue = 0, LEDGValue_next;

wire key1_edge;
wire key2_edge;

edge_detector
key1_edge_detector_inst (
    .clk(clk),
    .in(KEY[1]),
    .negedge_out(key1_edge)
);

edge_detector
key2_edge_detector_inst (
    .clk(clk),
    .in(KEY[2]),
    .negedge_out(key2_edge)
);

always @* begin : combinational_logic
    LEDGValue_next = LEDGValue;
    if (key1_edge)
        LEDGValue_next = {LEDGValue[7:0], 1'b1};
    else if (key2_edge)
        LEDGValue_next = {1'b0, LEDGValue[8:1]};
end

always @(posedge clk) begin : sequential_logic
    LEDGValue <= LEDGValue_next;
end
```

The key is that `key1_edge` and `key2_edge` signals are asserted only for a single clock cycle.

Comment: What you were trying to do is called asynchronous logic because there is no clock. It turns out that FPGAs are designed with the assumption that all logic will be synchronous and will use a clock. It is possible to implement asynchronous logic on an FPGA but right now this is an uphill battle and best left for experts.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Verilogger, but that looks like you are asking the code to trigger off edges of *two different* signals.  This is not in my experience synthesisable, but the synthesiser may have attempting *something* and warned you (amongst a plethora of other warnings) that it's done something other than you really meant.

---

EDIT: The following doesn't apply to the board mentioned as it has debouncing hardware on board (thanks to NathanFarrington for pointing that out) but I leave it here in case it is of use to other readers:

---

Even if the synthesiser succeeded, edge triggering on a switch input is a dreadful idea: [the switch will bounce several times](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm) when you press it, and the FPGA is easily fast enough to see all of those edges.

What you need is a process clocked from a good clock source (there's no doubt a crystal on board) which monitors both your switch signals on each clock event.

Keep a counter for each signal, increment it each time the signal is a `1`, decrement it each time the signal is a `0`.  Clamp these counters at `0` and some maximum time which allows plenty of time for the switch to settle (a few milliseconds will probably suffice).

Once the counter has reached either end of its "travel", only *then* do you take some action (like shifting your `LEDGValue`). Remember to wait for the switch to be released afterwards (waiting for the count to go to the other 'end').

Comment: This link says the four push buttons are already debounced using a Schmitt Trigger, so nothing has to be done in the FPGA: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece385/documents/DE2_UserManual.pdf

Comment: @NathanFarrington: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the details of that board... I'll update my answer

Answer (score -1):

Should it be

```
 always@(negedge KEY[1] OR negedge KEY[2])
```

Comment: 2 points: 1. Verilog is case-sensitive: `OR` should be `or`. 2. The comma is supported syntax as of the IEEE 1364-2001 spec.